# How to load resources through reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, plugins, reflection

When loading Resources through reflection, how can I be sure I am using the correct Resource Name when I call **DLLAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()**

The result of that call is a String[] containing 2 elements.

```
SDKSetupTool.MainForm.resources
SDKSetupTool.Properties.Resources.resources
```

If I make the same call to a VB Assembly, it returns 2 elements as well.

```
SDKSetupTool.MainForm.resources
SDKSetupTool.Resources.resources
```

The Last element has always been the correct Location containing the **Resources** from my tests. However, why must I have to parse out "**.resources**" in order for the **ResourceManager** to be able to load the Resources

```
//Load the DLL Assembly from the path that was passed in
var DLLAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(SelectedToolPath);

//Load the resource String so that we can bootstrap our Plugin
String RawResourceLocation = DLLAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()[1];
String ResourceLocation = RawResourceLocation.Substring(0, RawResourceLocation.LastIndexOf('.'));

//Load the resources into a Resource Manager
System.Resources.ResourceManager rman = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(ResourceLocation, DLLAssembly);

//Plugin Name
String PluginName = rman.GetString("PluginName");

//Plugin Description
String PluginDesc = rman.GetString("PluginDescription");

//Plugin Language (Currently only C# and VB.NET Supported)
 tring PluginLang = rman.GetString("PluginLanguage");

//Plugin's Entry Point (Because it is a DLL there is no Predefined Entry point. This is an alternative to that)
String PluginEntryPoint = rman.GetString("PluginEntryPoint");

//Discover our entry-point
var EntryPoint = DLLExtension.GetType(PluginEntryPoint);

//Grab the main method of the application
var MainMethod = EntryPoint.GetMethod("Main", new Type[] { });

MainMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

If I can consistently be able to load the Resources of an Assembly I will be able to load the plugin based on the String contained in the resources.

Comment: Side note: It is very surprising to see no reflection code in post that has title "How to load resources through reflection". You may want to edit title / sample code...

Comment: I added some more code to help with clarity. @AlexeiLevenkov